# Content of Excel Sheet isn´t displayed

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a problem. The following Java code should display the content of a excel file in the console of eclipse. First you can choose the excel file in a seperate window and next the content should be written in the console of eclipse.
Java Code:

```
package pack;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class WriteExcel {

public static String s;

public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int var = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(var == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        try {
            HSSFWorkbook datei = new HSSFWorkbook(new 
FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile()));
            HSSFSheet blatt = datei.getSheetAt(0);

            for(Row reihe: blatt) {
                for(Cell zelle : reihe) {
                    //zelle.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    System.out.println(zelle.getStringCellValue());
                    //s = zelle.getStringCellValue();
                    //System.out.println(s);
                }
            }

        } 
        catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It doesn´t display the content

Comment: First of all you should print the caught exception. And update your question instead of adding comments

Comment: Why tag excel - you describe a java problem...